# When will <td valign="top"> not work?

Tags: css, html-table, valign

Have you  ever concluded about this?

Now I've met one, very strange, don't know why.

My code:

```
<td valign="top">
    <input type="text" />
    <iframe scrolling="no" height="21px" frameborder="0" width="62px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="Server/SecCode.php">
    </iframe>
</td>
```

But it turns out to be that the "input" is valigned to the bottom,while "iframe" to the top.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't mean anything. Post your code, expected output, and the actual problem you have.

Comment: Are you using a TD to vertically align?

Comment: your TD's are within <TR>'s right? Show that code as well..

Comment: I think TD is more specific,say TR can't effect TD when explicitly overwritten,right?

Answer (score 8):

I experienced something similiar, when I added the css code

```
<td style=" vertical-align: top;" >
```

manually within the  td tag it corrected the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

change the doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree, a little more information will be helpful track down this problem.  If only for debugging purposes, you may want to try:

```
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" /><Br/>
<iframe scrolling="no" height="21px" frameborder="0" width="62px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="Server/SecCode.php">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Why do you want to add a "br"?

Comment: I've provided all related information.I can see from firebug that there are no other css rules applied.

Answer (score 0):

valign would only work if you used other kinds doctypes on your page, 
probably you have something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Try to remove the doctype, what isn't a good practice, and see if it's works..

So put only the html tag..